Cómo puedo relacionar una clave foranea relacionada con una clave compuesta?
CREATE TABLE tabla1(
    atributo1 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    atriburo2 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(atributo1, atributo2)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE tabla2(
    atributo1 INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE tabla2tabla1(
    atrib1 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    atrib2 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    INDEX(atrib1),
    INDEX(atrib2),
    FOREIGN KEY(atrib1) REFERENCES tabla2(atributo1) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(atrib2) REFERENCES tabla1(atributo1, atributo2) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

Este es el ejemplo que estoy estudiando y quisiera saber cuál es el error que tengo al relacionar la clave foránea con la clave compuesta de la tabla1... Les agradezco si me ayudan en entender, gracias :)

Hola Edward. 1.- Sería bueno que agregues el mensaje de error en tu pregunta. 2.- Las claves foráneas deben ser del mismo tipo de dato. Para más info, revisa FOREIGN KEY Constraints > Conditions and Restrictions

Aparte de lo que te indica @Marcos en su comentario, tienes al menos dos errores de sintaxis. El primero es que en tabla1 llamas a una columna atriburo2, cuando evidentemente debería ser atributo2, el segundo es que sobra el punto y coma en esta parte de tabla2: PRIMARY KEY; Luego, el tipo de relación que quieres establecer entre las tablas no tiene ningún sentido, no sólo porque los tipos de datos de las columnas relacionadas no coinciden, sino porque es un trabalenguas. Voy a verbalizar dichas relaciones: ...

En tabla2tabla1 relacióname la columna atrib1 con la columna atributo1 de tabla2, además, relacióname la columna atrib2 con las columnas atributo1 y atributo2 al mismo tiempo, esto es imposible así, porque no se puede relacionar una columna con dos columnas al mismo tiempo, además con diferentes tipos de datos, pero tú haz posible lo imposible. Eso es lo que le estás diciendo al SGBD en tu SQL. Sería bueno que expliques en qué consisten estas relaciones, y si usaras un ejemplo real mejor, porque nombres como tabla1, tabla2, atributo1, atributo2 no ayudan a entender.

Te falta una columna, probablemente attrib1, en FOREIGN KEY(atrib2) REFERENCES tabla1(atributo1, atributo2). Aquí están tus CREATE TABLE correctados: https://dbfiddle.uk/5qkQ4-MK

Gracias muchachos!!! No había percibido el ; y confirmo que el principal fallo que tenía era la inconsistencia en los tipos de datos. No pensé que los tipos tenían que coincidir al ser tablas distintas. Aplique sus recomendaciones y me funciona...muchas gracias!!!
